# removing extra mobile menu from the header

Tags: customization, menus, navigation

I have installed [burger theme](http://ketchupthemes.com/burger-theme/) and modified some template files to my needs. when I came to header, I decided to go with a simple bootstrap navigation bar, that doesn't require an extra menu. I took an example from getbootstrap.com and replaced ul>... with PHP script from original theme header.php adding bootstrap classes to ul element.  My current code in header.php looks like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <?php $menu_args = array('theme_location'=>'primary',
                               'container'=>false,
                               'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-menu');
          wp_nav_menu($menu_args);
      ?>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The problem I am facing now is that when I narrow down the window I have my original menu accessible via a burger menu button from bootstrap and an extra burger menu above my whole navigation section, that I cannot figure out where is defined to appear and what files should I edit to disable it?

While researching into this problem, I saw how a lot of people end up using css display none to hide it, I am interested in completely removing it, so the server won't need to render extra html that will end up being hidden. Thank you

**EDIT:**

Here is a printscreen of what the rendered version looks like

[image]

Here's the rendered part of what you can see on the picture

```
...
</head>
<body class="home page page-id-15 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar custom-background customize-support">
<div class="slicknav_menu">
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" class="slicknav_btn slicknav_collapsed" style="outline: none;">
<span class="slicknav_menutxt">Menu</span>
<span class="slicknav_icon">
<span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span>
<span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span>
<span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span>
</span>
</a>
<ul class="slicknav_nav slicknav_hidden" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" role="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-15 current_page_item menu-item-29"><a title="Home page" href="http://localhost/site/" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32"><a href="/site/menu/main/" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Menu</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a title="Contacts" href="http://localhost/site/contacts/" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div> address row </div>
<div> my navigation bar </div>
...
```

To provide more details here's the content of the top of the template file for this page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- carusel section -->
<?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=84]"); ?> 
...
```

the content of header.php I provided above

Comment: What do you want to disable? Please provide a screenshot and mark the thing that you want to remove.

Comment: the `icon-bar` markup makes the icon. It's hard to diagnose without seeing a rendered site as your markup is standard Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and finally finding the answer, I was correct that there is no code in template php files that generates the menu. While looking into functions.php file I noticed that this theme connects jquery.slicknav.min.js to the page, when I looked into not minified version I figured out that this the code that generates the extra menu at the top of the page. To get rid of it I commented out the line that adds the js file and the line that adds css for the slick nav

```
//wp_enqueue_script('burger_slicknav',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js',array('jquery'),'',true);
//wp_enqueue_style( 'burger_slicknav',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/slicknav.css','','','all');
```

No I no longer have the extra menu displaying in on my website as well I do not have any extra code or requests for appropriate page load.